# Listview page indicator

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `listview` that I implemented with infinite scrolling ability and I wanted to add a page indicator, for example `page 1/10` or `page 4/10`.

I receive the max number of pages from a `webservice` that gets called when the user scrolls to the bottom of the list. When the user scrolls to the last item in the list more data gets fetched and the current page would be incremented as `currentpage++`.

My question is that I would like when the user is scrolling back up to the top of the list instead of having the`nth` page being displayed still, it would change to `page 1`.

Each `page` contains 20 results, then at scrolling to the 20th item in the list a webservice fetches 20 more items and increments the global variable `currentpage` which is then stored displayed on the UI.

Comment: When the user starts scrolling upwards do you want to simply "jump" to page 1(which would be quite bad for the user experience?)?

Comment: I would want to change the current page number when they are viewing the results from the matching page. So when viewing results `1-20` it would show `page 1/10` and when viewing results `21-41` of the `listview` it would say `page 2/10`

Comment: Ok and you're trying to decrement that value after the user scrolls to an element from the previous page? If yes then use a `OnScrollListener` on the `ListView` and you'll notice there when the last element of the previous page appears.

Comment: Thanks for pointing in in the right direction at least, but I am unsure how to identify the results of each page differently.

Comment: checkout https://github.com/lalit3686/ListViewLoadingItems

Comment: @LalitPoptani I already have the loading items working properly, my question is purely about displaying an indicator on the screen to identify to the user the current page, but thanks.

Comment: @kabuto178 yes thats what the demo is for, it shows the paging count at the bottom of the ListView!

Comment: Oh I see now, I guess the amount of items loaded from the total amount will work as well

Comment: Decided to go with showing the total loaded amount out of the total amount of items.